# Vim strftime calculations

Tags: vim

I have a very simple ToDo file which looks like this :

```
130821 Go to the dentist
130824 Ask a question to StackOverflow
130827 Read the Vim Manual
130905 Stop reading the Vim Manual
```

I would like to calculate - each time I open the file - the number of days remaining until the different due dates (today is the 22nd of August 2013, i.e. 130822, in Paris), thus obtaining something like :

```
130821 -1 Go to the dentist
130824 2 Ask a question to StackOverflow
130827 5 Read the Vim Manual
130905 14 Stop reading the Vim Manual
```

but I do not know how to achieve that (and I do not know if it is reasonably possible : cf. glts'comment)

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that this is not at all trivial to do? Date calculations are hard and not something that can be done easily in a "strftime calculation". Why not use a proper calendar/todo list program?

Comment: are u on a Linux box? Do you have awk or date?

Comment: @glts : precisely, my Vim skills being limited, I do not distinguish between a trivial and a difficult question, and between a difficult and an "impossible" one. Your comment made me modify my question.

Comment: @Kent : no awk, Vim alone (but I have date)

Comment: I don't think vim is the right tool for this job.  You could easily write a python script to do this though.

Comment: @ThG is your date GNU date? you should know that strftime() is not portable

Comment: This seems way out of the scope of Vim.  Vim is a text editor.  It would make a lot more sense to execute a program (using your todo file as input) **before** opening it with Vim.  If you want to edit text manually, use a text editor.  If you want to manipulate text programmatically, use a program.

Comment: @Kent : I do not know...(Android device) Side question : is it possible to convert 130824 into an epoch time, subtract today's epoch time and convert the result in days ?

Comment: Please don't ask tangential questions in comments... On one hand I'd suggest asking a separate question.  However, you should just do some research in stead, given that there are already **tons** of questions about manipulating dates and timestamps.

Comment: @ThG I am not familiar with Android system. but if you have gnu date, you could do `d=$(($(date -d'130821' +"%j")-$(date +"%j")))` now the variable `d` has `-1`  `date --version` should tell you the version.

Comment: @jahroy : I formulated my question clumsily : it was not tangential, I was just wondering if this could be a solution. Your answers brought me to the conclusion that this cannot be done or rather should not be done in Vim. So, the question must be considered as closed. Thank you.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry about that, I thought your comment was asking a completely unrelated question.  To answer your question: yes, that's very easy to do with a normal programming language.  I would have no idea how to approach such a task using Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will do the desired substitution but the wrong calculation (it WON'T work as-is):

```
%s#\v^(\d{6})( -?\d+)?#\=submatch(1).' '.(submatch(1)-strftime("%y%m%d"))
```

See :help sub-replace-expression, :help submatch(), :help strftime().

Note my use of `\v` to put Vim's regex parser into "very magic" mode.

You could easily apply this whenever you load the file using a BufReadPost autocmd.

Something like:

```
augroup TODO_DATE_CALC
au!
au BufReadPost myToDoFileName %s#\v^(\d{6})( -?\d+)?#\=submatch(1).' '.(submatch(1)-strftime("%y%m%d"))
augroup END
```

[Find out the time since unix epoch for a certain date time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362570/find-out-the-time-since-unix-epoch-for-a-certain-date-time) shows how to get a unix time for a specific date, you can use the system() function in Vim to grab the result. But I don't have a system to test that out on at the moment. I think you might be out of luck, on Windows.

Unless you can change your file format to include unix time...then it ought to be fairly easy.

Comment: Not quite, almost...I'll try again

Comment: Nice try ... but honestly you're wasting your time. Date calculation isn't simply a matter of a `:s` command. See here for some hardcore date calculations done in Vim script: https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating/blob/master/autoload/speeddating.vim

Comment: "number of days" should be fairly easy to calculate given unix time. Or am I missing something? If not, the main problem would be to get a unix time out of a date string, for which there should be readily available external tools to be used with system(). I've edited for that...but can't actually test any of it at the moment (and don't know of a good utility on Windows).

Comment: @Ben : First of all, thank you for your answer (I was honestly beginning to think that I well deserved an infamous -1 for my question) ; as for your answer, it is almost perfect except for one glitch : change of month. For instance 130825 will work nicely and will output 2, but 130905 will give 82 instead of 13. Is there a way  to circumvent that problem ? Anyway my most grateful thanks (btw, I use Vim on Mac OSX and Android, syncing via Dropbox). And, of course, I accept your answer.

Comment: I think you'll need to use an external program to get the change in month accounted for. As glts said, it is not trivial to do that calculation in Vim. Maybe you can look at the "vim-speeddating" plugin he mentions in his comment, but I think the best method would be a system() command to get unix time from a date string. See the "Find out the time since unix epoch for a certain date time?" link I put in the answer; it looks like the "date" utility can do this on Linux. I don't know of one for Windows but I understand VBScript can do it, I imagine Perl and Python and such can as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although convinced by them, I was kind of disappointed by the answers given to my question. I tried to find a solution, and it seems I have almost succeeded. Needless to say, it is a clumsy contraption, but it works.

First of all, the file (slightly modified for testing purposes) :

```
130825 Past ToDo test 
130827 Today's ToDo test 
130829 In two days ToDo test 
130831 Another test 
130902 Change of month ToDo test 
131025 Another change of month test
```

Second, the data given by http://www.epochconverter.com :

```
1 day                   = 86400 seconds
1 month (30.44 days)    = 2629743 seconds
1 year (365.24 days)    = 31556926 seconds
```

Third, the function I tinkered :

```
function! DaysLeft()

  :normal! gg

  let linenr = 1
  while linenr <= line("$")
  let linenr += 1
  let line = getline(linenr)

  :normal! 0"ayiw
  :.s/\(\(\d\d\)\)\(\d\d\)\(\d\d\)\>/\1
  :normal! 0"byiw
  :execute "normal! diw0i\<C-R>a"

  :normal! 0"ayiw
  :.s/\(\d\d\)\(\(\d\d\)\)\(\d\d\)\>/\2
  :normal! 0"cyiw
  :execute "normal! diw0i\<C-R>a"

  :normal! 0"ayiw
  :.s/\(\d\d\)\(\d\d\)\(\(\d\d\)\)\>/\3
  :normal! 0"dyiw
  :execute "normal! diw0i\<C-R>a"

  let @l = strftime("%s")

  :execute "normal! 0wi\<C-R>=((\<C-R>b+30)*31556926+(\<C-R>c-1)*2629743+(\<C-    R>d-1)*86400+1-\<C-R>l)/86400\<Enter>\<tab>"

  exe linenr
  endwhile

  endfunction
```

Fourth, the results :

```
130825 -2   Past ToDo test
130827 0    Today's ToDo test
130829 1    In two days ToDo test
130831 3    Another test
130902 5    Change of month ToDo test
131025 58   Another change of month test
```

As you can see, there is a glitch : the 130829 ToDo is shown as being in 1 day instead of 2 days (because I did not do floating point calculation). But in fact I consider that as a programming glitch (among others…), but a psychologically sound one : In fact I have only one full day's work available.

It may be an exercise in futility, but this made me study : capture, loops, registers, and of course previous StackOverflow precious answers in order to give a pure Vim answer.

Thank you for all the improvements you will bring to my answer.

Comment: All of the leading `:` are unnecessary. I don't think you need the `.` in front of `s/...` The dot mean the current line and should be implied. I really doubt you need to do so much in normal mode. You could have just manipulated the string returned from getline and put it back with setline. (look at `:h substitute()`)

Comment: What can I say? My comments were somewhat harsh, nice to see that you took it as an opportunity to learn some Vim script ... btw, will your script survive the year change `13` to `14`? ;)

Comment: @glts : just tried 140105, and it rightly gave a 129 day answer. In fact, the principle is 13 (or 14) +30 (2000-1970 epoch time debut).

Comment: @FDinoff : as I said, this is a contraption, and it most certainly can be bettered. Why so much normal mode ? First of all, because it made things clear for me (I can read what is happening) ; second, I do not Know how to proceed otherwise (for instance, I do not "grok" what you mean by getline and setline). As you have guessed, I am learning Vim - and this was a good occasion - and may I add, I rather like that.

Comment: The comments weren't supposed to be harsh. Just things I noticed. As for what I meant by getline and setline, Take a look at the function `:h getline()` and `:h setline()` (You're already using getline so I didn't think I needed to mention that they were functions) Maybe I should have added parentheses after them...

Comment: @FDinoff : I did not take your comments as harsh at all. Besides, I must confess that I stole the principle of the while loop in a SO question and applied it without - ahem - fully understanding it. The rationale here was act first, think afterwards. I suppose one may sometimes learn that way ;-)